# How can I replace an OS without erasing the partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, kubuntu

I am using Lenovo IP320 with windows pre-installed. I dual-booted it with KUbuntu over 2 years ago, which crashes a lot these days. I am wondering if I can install another OS, say Ubuntu 20.04, in the same partition that I installed KUbuntu in without deleting the partition.

To avoid confusion with the OS names, here is what I basically want to do:

```
- OS-A is currently installed in a 250GB partition.
- I want to install OS-B in the same partition without losing the data and without deleting the partition. (This is because I don't have an external hard drive to back my data up to).
```

Can someone guide me through it?
Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: This is likely possible, but it would be very difficult to guide you through without knowing more about the specifics of your setup.  Also, the kind of operation you are doing is [relatively] risky - you should back up your data first.    Also, going from Kubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04 you may be better off simply switching the default desktop environment and upgrading to 20.04.  (Kubuntu and Ubuntu are the same base OS, with different Desktop environments)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:

#### Take backup of the installed OS

If the Kubuntu installed setup is of importance to you, it is best to preserve it. To do that:

1. Boot into the live session with your Ubuntu ISO, mount your partition with Kubuntu installed in it (let's call it target partition or just, TP).
2. Browse to the mount point of TP
3. create a directory at the root of TP named `kubuntu-files`
4. use cut and paste (through mouse) or `mv` command to move all directories under TP into `kubuntu-files` directory so that you are left with only one directory at the root of TP.
5. although off-drives backups are recommended, but since you don't have a secondary storage drive, you can use any other partition of your hard drive that has space more than the total space occupied by `kubuntu-files` directory, to save a copy of `kubuntu-files` directory.

   In case your other partition uses NTFS filesystem  or doesn't support Unix files and group permissions, then create a file in that partition large enough to contain `kubuntu-files` directory, format that file and setup ext4 filesystem in it, mount it, and copy the directory `kubuntu-files` into it. See [Create blank disk image for file storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667291/create-blank-disk-image-for-file-storage) if you need instructions in this direction.
6. use `sudo chattr +i mount_point_of_TP/kubuntu-files` to make the `kubuntu-files` directory immutable (resistant to modifications) so that you don't end up messing with the files yourself unless you're certain you want to mess with them.

Now, you have a backup of your files. The files from Kubuntu setup would not conflict with new installation of Ubuntu.

#### Time to install Ubuntu

When installing Ubuntu using its graphical installer, select "Manual partitioning", choose your TP, select it for the mount point `/` but **make sure to unselect/untick Format option.**

This way, Ubuntu would install in your TP *but your partition would not be formatted*. Go ahead with the installation. It should work out fine.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.